# How to paraphrase the phrase "sales is less likely to increase"

Tags: paraphrasing

When writing a paragraph, I face a phrase that "**sales are less likely to increase** in an increased competition market", I am trying to paraphrase the bolded phrase to one noun phrase or similar to that?

I think of "an increase in sales is unlikely" but it seems that it is still too long

Comment: How about "Sales aren't promising..." Also, " ...in an increasingly competitive market" would be better.

Comment: @user3169 we avoid using aren't in a paper writing tho.

Comment: "Sales do not look good"?

Comment: @NoviceMindset  If you don't like "aren't", use "are not".

Comment: @user3169 and Jack: so whether "sales are not promising" is similar to "sales are less likely to increase" ?

Comment: There is a lot of gray area here. "sales are less likely to increase" indicates a probability of decrease, but they still could increase. "sales are not promising" just indicates uncertainty. Without more context, I would stay with your original phrase if accuracy is important.

Comment: @user3169, I mean, I want to say "sales is more likely to decrease to stay the same"

Comment: I do not think that "sales are not promising" means the same thing here or is a good fit.  That implies that you expect the *absolute level* of sales to be poor.  On the other hand, the original sentence is talking about *relative changes* in sales numbers (increasing vs decreasing), which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: @Foogod, do you have any suggestions then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think that "an increase in sales is unlikely" is a perfectly reasonable and natural way to phrase what you are apparently trying to say, and would probably be my recommendation.

Alternately, you could say "sales increases are unlikely" (technically, "an increase in sales" is talking about the *state* of sales being higher than they were before, whereas "sales increases" are talking about the *events*/*transitions* of sales going from a lower point to a higher point, but they are often used somewhat interchangeably when talking about forward-looking statements)